# CSS Oriented Object When Should I use it?

Tags: css, oop, skin, oocss

So I learn about OOCSS, I found it really helpful, but I'm having trouble of how much should I separate the component im working on, for example I have a button, I separate the color from the structure -easy-, but should I also separate the font size so I can create a button with different font size?, and also separate the color font?, and also the font weight?, I mean what is the limit? is the limit based on the things I'm gonna need?
If that is right, is the way I made the next badge correct?
This is in a context where my font color of the badges is always gonna be white

This is the way I was taught

```
.badge {
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.badge-body-color {
  background-color: #00d9ff;
  color: white;/*this one*/
}
.badge-normal-color {
  background-color: #02cdf1;
  color: white;/*this one*/
}
```

This is the way I did it

```
.badge {
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;/*here is the change*/
}
.badge-small {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.badge-body-color {
  background-color: #00d9ff;
}
.badge-normal-color {
  background-color: #02cdf1;
}
```

Is it wrong because I put the color inside the structure?

Comment: In what sense could it be 'wrong'? And what is the word 'structure' (as opposed to purely visual stuff like color????) meaning? Seems to me if you want a canonical set up then you would put at least anything that isn't going to change into .badge. However, this question (and this comment!) is purely opinion based so it probably should be closed.

Comment: If you're really going to use many buttons, with many different sizes, colors, weights etc. then it makes sense to do that. If you're not, then the approach of OOCSS is more of a long-term thing. So, if you're going to have many different colors, it makes sense to separate color. Otherwise it's fine.